# How to convert beforeSend of ajax itno axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, axios

I'm switching from ajax to axios, this is the code I wanted to convert.

```
$.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: SPSConstants.SPS_BASE_URL + 'api/test?filter=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filter)),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                SPSUtils.getReqHeader(xhr, self, this, true);
            },
        }).done(function (result) {
            var resultObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
            let totalRecords = resultObj.pageInfo.total;
            let currentPage = self.state.currentPage;
            let currentRecords = resultObj.tollFreeNumberMasters;

            if (totalRecords !== 0 && currentRecords.length === 0) {
                
                self.setState({ currentPage: 1, pageInfo: { ...pageInfo, offset: 0 } }, () => {
                    self.loadTollFreeNumberTblData();
                });
            }
})
```

I've worked with axios earlier, so its not big of a deal. The only problem I'm facing is converting this part of ajax code into axios.

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    SPSUtils.getReqHeader(xhr, self, this, true);
},
```

is there any beforesend equivalent in axios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to get the xhr object before the http request.
It is the [Interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) that functions similarly in the Axios.

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  console.log(config);
});
```

However, if you set the interceptors function on an Axios instance, the callback will work for all requests from that instance. To make callback work only for specific requests, you need to create and use a new instance of Axios.

```js
const newAxios = axios.create();
newAxios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
  console.log(config);
});
```

Comment: If the answer is not what you want or lack, please let me know so that I can improve it!